# Error: 5080 : Form transaction registration failed - tried previous answers

Tags: opayo

I have searched the answers to similar questions asked about this SagePay error, and checked that the fixes don't appear to apply to my problem.

Specifically:

1. I am using a correct 2-letter country code for BillingCountry and     DeliveryCountry.
2. I am POSTing VPSProtocol, TxType and Vendor as well as the Crypt value.
3. I have re-checked that I am using the correct encryption key from the MySagePay test portal.

Now I **was** using http://localhost:8084/app/success and http://localhost:8084/app/failure for my success and failure URLs, since I thought that although these are (obviously) not visible externally, it shouldn't matter since SagePay is re-directing at the end of its part of the transaction. (**Is this assumption correct, or do these URLs need to be externally accessible?**) Some of the answers have thrown doubt on this, so I changed them to an external website I own, and I still get the same error.

Another line of thought is that the client I am developing for has already gone live, and there seem to be hints that once you have gone live, you no longer have access to the test server (**Is this true?**)

Is there anything else I should be checking? (Additional info: I'm using the SagePay api (sagepay-api-1.2.2.0.jar and related libraries) to validate the form contents and encrypt them.

Comment: "once you have gone live, you no longer have access to the test server, is this true?" No, it is still possible to access the test server.

Comment: 5080 is a generic error, which indicates 'something' is wrong! Post your crypt string, unencrypted and I'll run it through my Sage Pay account....

Answer (score 1):

I used the integration from https://github.com/tolzhabayev/sagepayForm-php

I had this error (5080) and spoke to SagePay support and they guided me to the MySagePay portal where you can view Invalid transactions to be able to troubleshoot this error easily!

Hope this helps someone.

Chris Rickards

Answer (score 0):

I had exact same problem and I tried everything that you described as well, one day after I found that the problem was in "VendorEMail" field, it had 2 email addresses separated by `;`, once I removed second and left only one email everything worked.